# CentOS Selenium - Preparing firefox profile

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying use to selenium with firefox on CentOS from command line like this:

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.19.0.jar -interactive

Then, I type:
cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=*firefox&2=http://www.google.com

Then it stucks on "Preparing Firefox profile..." part and crashes:

> 13:59:13.105 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile... 13:59:33.366 ERROR -
>   Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and clear all
>   session data

Please help me solve this, I'm quite new to the unix world.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have firefox installed?

Comment: Of course! The problem as far as I understand is that it cannot display on console. So I saw on web advice to set export DISPLAY=:0.0, but it still does not help

Comment: Do you have a GUI installed?  You need one for Selenium to work because it opens selenium in the GUI.  When you say command line do you mean a terminal run through the GUI or a terminal only login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could define a specific firefox profile (you have to create it first):

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -log SeleniumServer.log -firefoxProfileTemplate "PROFILEPATH" -interactive
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you pointing directly to the firefox executable, or are you pointing to an alias?

By default selenium should be pointing to your selenium binary, what is in /usr/bin is usually a script that interacts with the firefox executable.

Answer (score 1):

And for those wondering, if you're at the command line, you can create a profile like this:

```
firefox -CreateProfile profilename
```