# centOS, Jenkins, Firefox & Selenium GRID -- UnableToCreateProfileException

Tags: firefox, selenium, jenkins, centos, selenium-webdriver

We have Jenkins running headless on a centOS vm and access it via an http call on another computer.

I have a project for running UI Selenium Tests, all work well except the firefox ones. it is complaining about the profile not being on the centOS vm so it can forward it to the windows VM for testing.  Does anyone know how to get the latest and greatest firefox on centOS as yum only has 17 (headless CentOS VM) ? Also, where is the firefox profile stored on the CentOS OS if I just want to scp a current firefox profile on that VM ? Any other solution I have not thought of ?Let me know if more info is needed, jenkins error below:

`org.openqa.selenium.firefox.UnableToCreateProfileException: Given model profile directory does not exist: C:\Users\Selenium\FirefoxDriver
Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:52:59'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.verifyModel(FirefoxProfile.java:154)
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:92)
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:79)
com.igt.sqes.automation.selenium.factories.WebDriverFactory.createWebDriver(Unknown Source)
com.igt.sqes.automation.arcus.setup.ArcusTestSuiteSetup.setUp(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:277)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1194)
org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1338)
org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1307)`

it works fine when ran from a windows box cause the driver is in that location and can forward to test vm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way make a Firefox profile available to CentOS VM for use on a Windows VM running a Selnium node is to create a share on Windows pointing to a Firefox profile and then mounting that share on CentOS. Here are the steps I used to make this work:

1. On Windows, create a share of the directory the Firefox profile is in. The default Firefox profile is typically located in something like C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\427nha20.default. You may want to put the profile in a permissions-limited directory, such as one with read only privileges.
2. On CentOS, create a directory in the /mnt directory with the name you gave the Windows share. The names don't have to be the same but it helps to keep things consistent.
3. On CentOS, add the following line to the /etc/fstab file: 
   //windowsVMIP/windowsShareName /mnt/windowsShareName cifs username=windowsUser,password=windowsPassword,uid=123,gid=123,_netdev,ro 0 0
4. windowsVMIP is the IP of the VM with the share; windowsShareName is the name of the Windows share; /mnt/windowsShareName is the name you gave the Windows share; username and password are the credentials for the Windows user; uid is the user ID on CentOS; gid is the primary group ID on CentOS (you can get the uid and gid by executing grep jenkins /etc/passwd. They are the 3rd and 4th attributes respectively);
5. In CentOS, mount the Windows share manually by executing the following: mount -t cifs -o username=windowsUser,password=windowsPassword,uid=123,gid=123 //windowsVMIP/windowsShareName /mnt/windowsShareName
6. cd to /mnt/windowsShare and ls to make sure the mount succeeded
7. Configure the Selenium Firefox driver by setting the FirefoxDriver.PROFILE capability to point to the CentOS mounted share. Then pass the capabilities to the Selenium Webdriver when creating it. For example in Java:

   `FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("/mnt/windowsShareName"));
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);

   WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(gridHubURL), capabilities);`
8. The Firefox profile will be sourced from the CentOS share and forwarded to the Windows VM Selenium node after the Selenium driver is instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Try to install newer version of Firefox**

In order to do that you can use Remi repository

```
## Remi Dependency on CentOS 6 and Red Hat (RHEL) 6 ##
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

## CentOS 6 and Red Hat (RHEL) 6 ##
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

[Step by step instruction](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/install-firefox-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)

**2. Try to copy existing profile and specify it explicitly**

Please see the following thread: [CentOS Selenium - Preparing firefox profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414626/centos-selenium-preparing-firefox-profile)

Comment: will look at as soon as I can!